# Pivot_longer issue with additional column contents?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a csv file which I have brought into R, I need to get it in a tidy format. This requires pivoting the data so that the current columns are in a single column.

There are dates at the start of each column which should be maintained and assigned NA if possible. I can always take these rows out for now and add them back in at the end.

There are four important parameters to capture. Each row of data should have a date, station, turbine (code indicated by AFG...), and value. The main issue I have is that for some stations there is a secondary value for turbine (meaning that at a specific date the turbine was changed) therefore if I simply pivot longer it doesn't work properly.

See the example dataset below with station 3. What should happen is that once a certain date is reached the (i.e. after the 17th) then the rows relating to station 3 should be:

```
#>         date  station turbine value
#> 1 2022-01-18 station3  AFG143     B
```

Obviously the real data is more complicated than this but I think the reprex captures the issue. Could someone advise on how to achieve this?

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)


# regex data

df <- data.frame(
  date = seq(ymd("2022-01-05"),
    ymd("2022-01-31"),
    by = "1 day"
  ),
  station1 = sample(c("A", "B", "C", " "), 27, replace = TRUE),
  station2 = sample(c("A", "B", "C", " "), 27, replace = TRUE),
  station3 = sample(c("A", "B", "C", " "), 27, replace = TRUE)
)


a <- data.frame(date = ymd("2022-01-01"), station1 = "", station2 = "", station3 = "")
b <- data.frame(date = ymd("2022-01-02"), station1 = "", station2 = "", station3 = "")
c <- data.frame(date = ymd("2022-01-03"), station1 = "", station2 = "", station3 = "")
d <- data.frame(date = ymd("2022-01-03"), station1 = "AFG221", station2 = "AFG514", station3 = "AFG111")

df <- bind_rows(a, b, c, d, df)

df <- dplyr::add_row(
  df,
  date = ymd("2022-01-17"),
  station1 = "",
  station2 = "",
  station3 = "AFG143",
  .before = 17
)
# removing line for just the example dataframe
df[-18,]


#>          date station1 station2 station3
#> 1  2022-01-01                           
#> 2  2022-01-02                           
#> 3  2022-01-03                           
#> 4  2022-01-03   AFG221   AFG514   AFG111
#> 5  2022-01-05        A                 C
#> 6  2022-01-06        C                 C
#> 7  2022-01-07        B        A         
#> 8  2022-01-08                 B        B
#> 9  2022-01-09                 A         
#> 10 2022-01-10        B        C        B
#> 11 2022-01-11        C        B        C
#> 12 2022-01-12        B        A        A
#> 13 2022-01-13        B        C        B
#> 14 2022-01-14        B        B        C
#> 15 2022-01-15        C        A        C
#> 16 2022-01-16        C                 A
#> 17 2022-01-17                     AFG143
#> 19 2022-01-18        A                 B
#> 20 2022-01-19        B        A        A
#> 21 2022-01-20        A        B        C
#> 22 2022-01-21        B                 C
#> 23 2022-01-22                 A         
#> 24 2022-01-23        A        A        A
#> 25 2022-01-24        A        B        A
#> 26 2022-01-25        C        A        C
#> 27 2022-01-26                 B        A
#> 28 2022-01-27        A        A         
#> 29 2022-01-28        B        A        C
#> 30 2022-01-29                           
#> 31 2022-01-30        C        C        B
#> 32 2022-01-31        B        C        C
```

Desired result (only first three rows shown)

```
#>         date  station turbine value
#> 1 2022-01-05 station1  AFG221     A
#> 2 2022-01-05 station2  AFG514     NA
#> 3 2022-01-05 station3  AFG111     C
```

Comment: Why is the `value` for turbine `AFG514` on `2022-01-05` equal to `B` when `station2` has no non-missing data on or prior to that date?  How should the missing data up to `2022-01-03` be preserved when the *first three lines* of your desired result do not have any missing values?  I'm afraid your example is a long way from being a reprex.  In the long run I would strongly urge your data provider to improve the format of their input.

Comment: You say "There's a bunch of empty rows with dates at the start of each column which should be maintained and assigned NA." but in your expected output you directly start at 2022-01-05. This seems to be contradictory?

Comment: @Limey Sorry, it should be missing. I regenerated the dataframe and it changed the data. I'll correct. Yes, tell me about it....

Comment: @bretauv, I simplified it to just show rows with data, but theoretically it should be just date with empty rows between the 2022-01-01 and 2022-01-05.

Comment: The data doesn't explicitly say that values are missing, there are just no content in the cells. Which basically I want to code as an NA, or a space. I can change to whatever later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps `dplyr`s new non-equi `join`s could be useful here:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_turbines <- 
  df %>% 
  filter(if_any(starts_with("station"), ~str_detect(., "^AFG"))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-date, names_to = "station", values_to = "turbine") %>% 
  filter(turbine != "") %>% 
  mutate(date_end = coalesce(lead(date) %m-% days(1), as.Date("9999-12-31")),
         .by = station) %>% 
  rename(date_start = date)
```

First we create a dataframes for turbines:

```r
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  date_start station  turbine date_end  
  <date>     <chr>    <chr>   <date>    
1 2022-01-03 station1 AFG221  9999-12-31
2 2022-01-03 station2 AFG514  9999-12-31
3 2022-01-03 station3 AFG111  2022-01-16
4 2022-01-17 station3 AFG143  9999-12-31
```

Then we join this with the dataframe without turbines:

```r
df %>% 
  filter(!if_any(starts_with("station"), ~str_detect(., "^AFG") | . == "")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-date, names_to = "station") %>% 
  left_join(df_turbines, 
            by = join_by(date >= date_start, 
                         date <= date_end,
                         station == station)) %>% 
  select(-date_start, -date_end)
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 81 × 4
   date       station  value turbine
   <date>     <chr>    <chr> <chr>  
 1 2022-01-05 station1 "B"   AFG221 
 2 2022-01-05 station2 "B"   AFG514 
 3 2022-01-05 station3 " "   AFG111 
 4 2022-01-06 station1 "A"   AFG221 
 5 2022-01-06 station2 "C"   AFG514 
 6 2022-01-06 station3 " "   AFG111 
 7 2022-01-07 station1 "B"   AFG221 
 8 2022-01-07 station2 "B"   AFG514 
 9 2022-01-07 station3 " "   AFG111 
10 2022-01-08 station1 " "   AFG221 
# … with 71 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: This seems to work great, I'll try on the full dataset and report back / accept answer. I'll need to look at what this is doing in detail because the whole left_join line is new.

Comment: @Dasr I made some small adjustments to the code.